# DBMS_JOB over triggers

Tags: sql, oracle11g, job-scheduling, triggers, dbms-scheduler

I want to know if DBMS_JOB can be used over Trigger.

My requirement is that I want the job to run when Table1 is inserted or updated. I want to know that if I schedule the job every 1 minute to pick the updated/inserted row based on date whether it will put any load on my DB(though the update or insert will not happen frequently). I am using Oracle 11g.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to put trigger that insert data in another table named EVT_Table1 (when you have update or insert) and than let your job execute action on the EVT_Table1.